# geom_smooth and geom_line regression line creation

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am getting two outputs for following steps in R:

1. `ggplot(mario_kart, aes(y = totalPr, x = duration, color=cond)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = 0)`
2. `ggplot(mario_kart, aes(y = totalPr, x = duration, color=cond)) + geom_point() + geom_line(data=broom::augment(lm(totalPr~duration+cond,data=mario_kart)), aes(y=(.fitted)))`

I want to understand how data is getting manipulated and exactly how can I know whether I am using the correct method in ggplot.

Comment: I think perhaps the first method fits a separate `lm` model for each `color`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package `ggplot` produce graphs in R. You should use a data frame as your data and manipulate the variables that you are interested. Using Aesthetics, you will describe how your data will relate to your plots. You also, may specified your layer as `geom_point`, `geom_histogram`, geom_smooth and others...

For exemple,

```
ggplot(mario_kart, aes(y = totalPr, x = duration, color=cond)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = 0)
```

Here you used `mario_kart` data then acessed the variables `totalPr` and `duration` as your aesthetics. After, you call the kind of layer you used, that is, `geom_point()` and `geom_smooth`. Which kind of layer has your own paramers, so you defined `geom_smooth` the method "lm".

I advise you use pipi operator "%>%", what allows you to write codes more readble.

As follow:

```
mario_kart %>% ggplot(aes(y = totalPr, x = duration, color=cond)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = 0)
```